# Triggering tasks from email in a node server

Tags: express, email, smtp, imap, pop3

After having done various research I cannot find the best way to achieve this:

- I have a Node Express server, providing services to various users
- I would like any user to be able to send an email to user-id@mydomain.com
- Upon reception, I would like to trigger a specific task in the server, to process the email body.

**Option 1**

I was first hoping to find some kind of SMTP node package that I could simply embed in the server, and configure it with the various  email addresses to be accepted,  and with a callback function to trigger the task whenever an email arrives. Does this exist?

**Option 2**

Another option would be to install a SMTP server (ideally in a Docker container, and in any case on Linux), to handle the storage of each user mailbox. My Node server would then periodically check each user mailbox via POP3 or IMAP, and trigger the task whenever an email is found. But this seems a bit overkill to me:

- I don't need to store the emails once the task is performed
- This would be less responsive than having a callback like in the first option, and would require a periodic check of all users, whereas in practice, such emails will arrive very sporadically.

In this approach, what would you recommend as a dockerized SMTP server, and as a POP3/IMAP node package to retrieve and process emails?

**Option 3?**

Would there be any other approach?

Any recommendation welcome!!
Many thanks!

Comment: Option 2 running a script on reception would be ideal.  Using IMAP/POP to _pull_ messages when you have an SMTP that can _push_ it to you would work way better. All major SMTP unix servers can be set to run some sort of code on receipt of an email, and you can use this to push it to where you want it.

Comment: Thank you Max! I have indeed spent a few hours trying configuring the mailu/postfix docker image, but encountered various issues. Searching further on the web I have found the smtp-server Node package which seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Node `smtp-server` package can do the job. Combined with `mailparser` I can retrieve a Javascript object with the email structure fully parsed.